# how to insert rows in table1 where col1 and col2 of table1 doesn't match col1 and col2 of table2

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a `table1` such has:

```
date       ticker   po       tag1
2016-10-13    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-13    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-13     EP -647.0000  SV
2016-10-14    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-14    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-14     EP -647.0000  SV
```

and `table2`

```
date       ticker   po       tag1
2016-10-14    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-14    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-14     EP -647.0000  SV
2016-10-15    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-15    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-15     EP -647.0000  SV
```

I want to insert news rows in `table1` from `table2` where the combination of `ticker`, `date` and `tag1` doesn't match `table1` combination
such has:

```
date       ticker   po       tag1
2016-10-13    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-13    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-13     EP -647.0000  SV
2016-10-14    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-14    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-14     EP -647.0000  SV
2016-10-15    UX1 -206.0000  SV
2016-10-15    UX2 -617.0000  SV
2016-10-15     EP -647.0000  SV
```

I am fairly new to SQL server and this seems very straight forward but I can't make it work.

thank you

Comment: Do you have any constraints on your tables? Do they have primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO table1
            (date,ticker,po,tag1)
SELECT date, ticker, po, tag1
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table1 t1
                   WHERE  t1.ticker = t2.ticker
                          AND t1.date = t2.date
                          AND t1.tag1 = t2.tag1)
```

The `sub-query` returns 1 when there is a matching record found and `NOT EXISTS` will eliminate those records

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. what does SELECT 1 means in the WHERE NOT EXIST, this part confuse me a bite

Comment: @StevenG The `sub-query` returns 1 when there is a matching record found and `NOT EXISTS` will eliminate those records

Answer (score 1):

you can also use join

```
insert into table1
select t2.*
from
table2 t2
join
table1 t1
on t1.col1<>t2.col1 
and t1.col2<>t2.col2
```